# adblock active then don't open hyper link into new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to avoid hyper link open into new tab when user have active any kind of ad blocker on his site.

Currently I have one myFile.js in my root directory with this content:

```
jQuery.adblock = false;
```

and I have this function to detect adblocker :

```
function checkAdBlocker() {     

    if($.adblock){
          alert('You have adblock active');
    }

}
```

now issue is how I can prevent to whole hyper links of my site to not open into new tab.

Comment: `$('a').attr('target', '_self');`

Comment: I think Andrew is right.

Comment: okay let me implement this sooper dooper line of code ;)

Comment: @AndrewEvt can you pls put your comment as answer, it worked for me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent ALL links opening on your page in new tabs, and open them in the same tab - you can use (after `load` event):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').attr('target', '_self');
});
```

It will add `target="_self"` attribute to all `a` tags in your DOM.

Read more about `<a>` tag and it's attributes here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Information about `_self` and other values is under the `target` attribute description.